# How do I read the source code of shell commands?

Tags: linux, command, gnu-coreutils

I would like to read the actual source code which the linux commands are written with. I've gained some experience using them and now I think it's time to interact with my machine at a deeper level.

I've found some commands here http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/GNU. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find basic commands such as 'ls' which seems to me easy enough to begin.

How exactly do I read the source code of the simple shell commands like 'ls'? 
I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Visit for example: http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/coreutils/ You can browse the code online. Open one of the archives and check for the src folder.

Comment: Hi, I find an utilities too, it is util-linux. You can find it [here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux)

Comment: `ls` is not part of Linux, it is part of Gnu. Gnu runs on Linux and other kernels.

Comment: I find github interface easier for reading code, https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c

Answer (score 196, accepted):

All these basic commands are part of the `coreutils` package.

You can find all information you need here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/

If you want to download the latest source, you should use git:

`git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/coreutils`

To install git on your Ubuntu machine, you should use apt-get (git is not included in the standard Ubuntu installation):

`sudo apt-get install git`

Truth to be told, here you can find specific source for the `ls` command:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c

Only 4984 code lines for a command 'easy enough' as `ls`... are you still interested in reading it?? Good luck! :D

Comment: OMG! I thought it was a bit easier... Well the path is longer and harder than expected :-)

Comment: Try the [source for `cat`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c). It's only 767 lines.

Comment: `Only 4984 code lines ...` -- It seems in 4 years and 3 months `ls` has become another 57 lines more complex.

Comment: I remember once I tried to understand why `wc` is so much faster than equivalent Java program. So I looked at the code ... OMG is it optimized for disk reads, buffering inputs, etc or what :)

Comment: @yǝsʞǝlA I'm not proficient in C; how do you tell what it's optimizing for? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Yes, I am definitely interested in reading all ~5000 lines of code, I'd be fine if it were 10000. My results of getting file sizes in my program sometimes differ from what `ls` shows, and `ls` is correct. I believe there is some caching happening that prevents my program from seeing the latest file size. If `ls` is correct, I only need to figure out what it's doing, and do the same thing myself. That's why it's open source. If no one wanted to read it then open source would be called "closed source" ;-) Thanks for the link straight to `ls`. It's just what I needed +1

Answer (score 151):

Direct links to source for some popular programs in [`coreutils`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/):

- [`cat`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c) (767 lines)
- [`chmod`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/chmod.c) (570 lines)
- [`cp`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/copy.c) (2912 lines)
- [`cut`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cut.c) (831 lines)
- [`date`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/date.c) (570 lines)
- [`df`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/df.c) (1718 lines)
- [`du`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/du.c) (1112 lines)
- [`echo`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/echo.c) (272 lines)
- [`head`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/head.c) (1070 lines)
- [`hostname`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/hostname.c) (116 lines)
- [`kill`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/kill.c) (312 lines)
- [`ln`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ln.c) (651 lines)
- [`ls`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c) (4954 lines)
- [`md5sum`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/md5sum.c) (878 lines)
- [`mkdir`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/mkdir.c) (306 lines)
- [`mv`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/mv.c) (512 lines)
- [`nice`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/nice.c) (220 lines)
- [`pwd`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/pwd.c) (394 lines)
- [`rm`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/rm.c) (356 lines)
- [`rmdir`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/rmdir.c) (252 lines)
- [`shred`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/shred.c) (1325 lines)
- [`tail`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c) (2301 lines)
- [`tee`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tee.c) (220 lines)
- [`touch`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/touch.c) (437 lines)
- [`wc`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/wc.c) (801 lines)
- [`whoami`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/whoami.c) (91 lines)

[Full list here.](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/)

Comment: Thanks for listing with number of lines. :)

Comment: Do you have `su`?

Comment: @Drew, do you have any idea if there are shell commands actually written in shell script?

Comment: I don't see the find command in here like
```find . -type f -name '*.csproj' ```
I am trying to see how that algorithm looks

Answer (score 6):

`ls` is part of coreutils. You can get it with git :

```
git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/coreutils
```

You'll find coreutils listed with other packages (scroll to bottom) on [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/software.html).

Comment: or browse the repo online ... eg. http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c

Answer (score 6):

Actually more sane sources are provided by http://suckless.org look at their `sbase` repository:

`git clone git://git.suckless.org/sbase`

They are clearer, smarter, simpler and suckless, eg `ls.c` has just 369 LOC -

http://git.suckless.org/sbase/file/ls.c.html

After that it will be easier to understand more complicated GNU code.

Answer (score 2):

You can have it on github using the command

```
git clone https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils.git
```

You can find all the source codes in the src folder.

> You need to have [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) installed.

Things have changed since 2012, `ls` source code has now 5309 lines

Answer (score 1):

CoreUtils referred to in other posts does NOT show the real implementation of most of the functionality which I think you seek. In most cases it provides front-ends for the actual functions that retrieve the data, which can be found here:

It is build upon [Gnulib](https://github.com/rofl0r/gnulib) with the actual source code in the [lib-subdirectory](https://github.com/rofl0r/gnulib/tree/master/lib)

Comment: Is this resource official or a third party repository?

Comment: @Merlin: it is official

Answer (score 0):

BSD distributions are actually a nice way of reading the source code, by using their repositories, since it is all packed into one place, and you can view how historically the source code has evolved, or changed. So why not use BSD repos , such as [NetBSD](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/?only_with_tag=MAIN) or [OpenBSD](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/)  for this task.

Answer (score -1):

```
    cd ~ && apt-get source coreutils && ls -d coreutils*
```

You should be able to use a command like this on ubuntu to gather the source for a package, you can omit `sudo` assuming your downloading to a location you own.