# Where is the command 'ls' kernel source code?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, kernel, ls, vfs

What I want to know is the command 'ls' flow

example : "ls -> some_function() in kernel -> [VFS function] -> make dentry object"

I think when I type 'ls' in command line, a function in kernel is called at first.

What is the first function called in kernel source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find source code for Linux core commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528267/where-can-i-find-source-code-for-linux-core-commands)

Comment: `ls` is not part of Linux, it is part of Gnu. Gnu runs on Linux and other kernels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a duplicate of [Where can I find source code for Linux core commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528267/where-can-i-find-source-code-for-linux-core-commands)

But you can find the source code of `ls` here:

http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/bin/ls/ls.c?rev=1.67&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup

Answer (score 1):

You can also view it here, with syntax highlighting and easier navigation
https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/tree/master/src