# Can't find ls -l source code

Tags: c, ls

I am currently writing a C program in which I need to recreate ls and a few of its options. I have no idea where to start when it comes with -l. I am looking around for the source code but I can't seem to find anything. Any help pointing me in the right direction to recreating -l would be very helpful.

Comment: Um. You could do your own work, in which case I would ask you, what does the -l flag do? Gives you file attributes. Get those file attributes in C if your users uses the -l flag and then display then. Easy peasy.

Comment: I feel like it defeats the purpose of recreating ls if it is for educational purposes, as you might as well just copy and paste the code into your version. But, you might want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528267/where-can-i-find-source-code-for-linux-core-commands

Comment: Try looking at the source of busybox. It has ls but with fewer options so its code will be simpler.

Comment: Why don't you look at the manual page for `ls` and then take a look at the low-level file structure data that you can get using the standard library.  That's all that `ls` uses, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find source code of many GNU commands here : http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=tree;f=src;h=df809d8aabc8c9207166f3f3f1e814cc62560c8d;hb=master, including ls.

Hope this help !