# Aligning columns in ls

Tags: c, ls

i'm writing an implementation of ls command but i found a problem with
the columns, i want to align them like the real ls -l

```
drwx------@   3   haxor123 candidate  102  Oct  3 14:43 Applications
drwxr-xr-x    21   haxor123 candidate  714  Nov 29 21:07 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x    4   haxor123 candidate  136  Nov  6 19:54 Documents
drwx------    9   haxor123 candidate  306  Nov 28 22:28 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x@   396   haxor123 candidate  13464  Nov 29 19:52 Library
drwx------+   3   haxor123 candidate  102  Aug  9 16:38 Movies
drwx------+   4   haxor123 candidate  136  Oct  5 14:13 Music
drwxr-xr-x    3   haxor123 candidate  102  Oct  4 23:23 PicineRe
drwxr-xr-x    4   haxor123 candidate  136  Oct  4 23:52 PicineRee
drwxr-xr-x    3   haxor123 candidate  102  Oct  4 22:32 PicineReloaded
drwx------+   4   haxor123 candidate  136  Nov 11 16:46 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x    6   haxor123 candidate  204  Nov 12 21:38 exam-basedir
lrwxr-xr-x    1   haxor123 candidate  34  Jul 16 10:12 goinfre -> 
/Volumes/Storage/goinfre/haxor123/
drwxr-xr-x    4   haxor123 candidate  136  Oct  3 15:14 s
```

That's a part from ls -l function

```
temp = list;
ft_putstr("total ");
printblocks(list);
ft_putchar('\n');
while (temp != NULL)
{
    lstat(temp->full_path, &fstat);
    ft_permissions(temp, fstat);
    ft_putstr("  ");
    bytes1 = ft_itoa(fstat.st_nlink);
    ft_putstr(bytes1);
    ft_putstr(get_user(fstat));
    bytes = ft_itoa(fstat.st_size);
    len = ft_strlen(bytes);
    ft_putstr(ft_strjoin(bytes, "  "));
    get_time(fstat, temp);
    temp = temp->next;
    if (temp != NULL)
        ft_putchar('\n');
```

Comment: What is preventing you from doing so?

Comment: i tried a lot of solutions but no one works , i need to align every columns like the exact ls

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to read the source code for GNU commands directly, you can do so...and it may be a good learning experience:

[Where can I find source code for Linux core commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528267/where-can-i-find-source-code-for-linux-core-commands)

In particular, here is `ls.c`:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c

The only way to know precisely "how `ls` does it" comes from that file.  We are not psychic (at least I am not) so if you're going to be asking about any other programming method, it needs to be self-contained in your question what you're specifically trying to achieve and why you can't achieve it.